How to use a signal of previous testcase?
I am encountering an issue in Canoe where test cases produce false positive results due to interference from previous test runs. Specifically, I am testing a Device Under Test (DUT) that sends the signal "Alarm_Temperature" under two conditions: when the temperature drops below 0, and when it rises above 100.
In my setup, Testcase A simulates a temperature below 0 and uses the "Await Value Match" method to check if the "Alarm_Temperature" signal was received. Testcase B simulates a temperature above 100 and checks for the same signal. The problem arises because if the DUT sends "Alarm_Temperature" during Testcase A, Testcase B will always pass, regardless of whether the DUT actually sends the signal during Testcase B.
I attempted to address this in VT Test Studio by using the "Wait for Update Signal" checkbox. However, this introduced timing dependencies. For example, if the DUT sends the "Alarm_Temperature" signal before the "Await Value Match" condition is checked, the test fails because the signal was not captured correctly.
The cleanest solution I can think of is to reset the trace or clear the recorded signals after each test case, effectively isolating them. Ideally, I would want to stop and restart the simulation between test cases to ensure no residual data interferes with subsequent tests, but I haven't been able to find an option for this. I'm looking for a way to prevent test cases from affecting each other.
I cannot share screenshots but I can write it with a simple example.

Testcase 1:
1.send ONCE can message "Alarms" with value "Temperature_alarm". 
2.await value match "Alarms" == "Temperature_alarm".



Testcase 2: 
1. await value match "Alarms" == "Temperature_alarm" 


When you start canoe and then run first the second testcase alone it fails as it should. But if you run the testcase1 just once, testcase2 will always produce pass. The environment of canoe is not testcase independent. I cannot use the option "wait for signal update" in await value match. 

Show at least some screenshots of your tests in vTESTstudio together with the test report. It is impossible to follow the description without seeing what is actually going on.

I edited the question. I hope it can illustrate the scenario.

You can use the Reset command to reset signals. However, this will cause bus traffic; not sure if this is acceptable. Apart from that, I do not get, why you cannot use Await value match with the wait for update option. From your description, it is not clear, how "the DUT sends the signal before" can happen.

Thanks for the Input! Does reset delete the occurrence of the signal in canoe? As for the second part: I hope I do not make it now too complicated. When setting a state we have to set the whole state temperature, pressure, speed etc, one after the other simultaneously is sadly not possible, but the alarm can happen in-between. So when we set the temperature we cannot immediately wait for the alarm.  You gave me the Idea of checking for occurrence. This would work, but there are so many tests, rewriting is too extensive. A "clear all signal from trace/canoe" option would be a perfect solution.

AFAIK Reset will only set the signal to its initial value (as specified in the DBC). From your description, the only viable way I see is to setup a Check at the beginning of the test case. Maybe you can do this in a reusable function or in the preparation step, which could reduce the effort.
